# how to distribute items in number of lists?

Tags: c#

**Question:** How to distribute items in number of lists? following are examples:

- Imagine I have a 8 lists, and 5 items. in this case list 1 to 5 will have 1 item.  rest of lists remain empty.
- Now If I have 8 lists and 16 items each list will have 2 items.
- If I have 8 lists and 11 items, list 1 to 3 will have two items. rest of the lists will have 1 item.

---

```
var items = new List<object>();
var containers = new List<List<object>>();

int c = -1; // indexer for container.

for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    // disturbute items to containers

    if (i % (items.Count/containers.Count) == 0) c++; // this is wrong. when to increment?

    containers[c].Add(items[i]);
}
```

I'm pretty sure only if statement is wrong. Its getting confusing how to handle `i`.

Comment: You can state this in LINQ really easily: `items.Select((item, index) => new{item, grpIndex = index % numContainers}).GroupBy(x => x.grpIndex).Select(grp => grp.Select(x => x.item).ToList()).ToList()`

Comment: Now that you've seen some solutions, take a step back and ask how you managed to write an incorrect program in the first place: *you got the mutation of a variable wrong*. The variable had to mutate because you need it to be correct in your imperative algorithm. Notice that spender's algorithm given in the comment above is short, clear, obviously correct, and *has no variable mutations or loops*. You'll write fewer bugs and have programs that are easier to understand if you ask yourself "how can I eliminate this variable mutation? How can I eliminate this loop?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<object>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        var containers = new List<List<object>>() { new List<object>(), new List<object>(),  new List<object>()};

        int c = 0; // indexer for container.
        int containerCount = containers.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++, c++)
        {
            c = c % containerCount;
            containers[c].Add(items[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the algorithm. When inserting item, you insert it to a list and then move to next one. When reaching last list, start inserting back to the first. Code (written in notepad, so may not compile):

```
var items = new List<object>();
var containers = new List<List<object>>();

int c = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    c++; // move to next container

    // when reached to the end, insert again to first list
    if (c == containers.Count)
    {
        c = 0;
    }
    containers[c].Add(items[i]);
}
```

This can be made a bit shorter:

```
var items = new List<object>();
var containers = new List<List<object>>();

int c = 0;
foreach (int item in items)
{
    c = (c == containers.Count - 1) ? 0 : c + 1;
    containers[c].Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to isolate this behavior into something reusable and testable:

```
public class ListBalancer
{
    public void BalanceItemsBetweenLists<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> input,
        IEnumerable<IList<T>> targets)
    {
        var inputArray = input as T[] ?? input.ToArray();
        var targetArray = targets as IList<T>[] ?? targets.ToArray();
        var currentTargetIndex = 0;
        foreach (var item in inputArray)
        {
            targetArray[currentTargetIndex].Add(item);
            currentTargetIndex++;
            if (currentTargetIndex == targetArray.Length) currentTargetIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ListBalancerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void BalancesListsWhenAddingItems()
    {
        var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 11);
        var targets = Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(n => new List<int>()).ToArray();
        new ListBalancer().BalanceItemsBetweenLists(source, targets);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, targets[0].Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, targets[1].Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, targets[2].Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, targets[3].Count);
    }
}
```

It seems like a little bit of extra work. But you probably found that the process of debugging when it didn't do what was expected took a little extra time, too. It might have been necessary to start a console application or some other app to test the behavior. If you write a class with a unit test you might still have to debug, but it's faster and more self-contained. You finish the one class with the one behavior, test it, and then move on.

Personally I found that once I formed the habit I could write code a little faster and with fewer bugs because I made my debugging process smaller and easier.

Comment: There is no need for the inputArray variable - just use input variable instead. And consider making targets an IList<List to avoid the need for targetArray as well.

Comment: @mjwills: Though I take your point, you are minimizing the wrong thing. The correct attitude is not "I can eliminate this variable because it is unnecessary, so I should". The right attitude is "If I have one variable per concept, and I mutate variables as little as possible, then my program becomes easier to understand and more likely correct."  Variables are *cheap*. There's no reason to try to minimize how many are used.

Comment: If I'm following my own practice of using a more general type then `IList<T>` would have been preferable to `List<T>`. (Editing answer.)

Comment: I did not explain myself properly there @EricLippert - thanks for highlighting. I should have said instead - "Your use of inputArray rather than input directly means that in some cases (i.e. if you don't pass an IList) you will materialise the IEnumerable as an extra array (which has a memory cost)."

Comment: As well as "There is a similar, but slightly different, issue with your targets and targetArray. lList<IList<T>> is a better fit for the that parameter type, since it clearly shows to the caller that aspects of IList (e.g. direct positional indexing) are required. If someone needs to ToArray, I'd recommend it be the caller not the BalanceItemsBetweenLists method itself).

Comment: @ScottHannen An IList<List> is likely better than IList<IList> (or IEnumerable<IList>) since the latter will accept an array of arrays at compile time, but will throw an exception at runtime (due to use of Add).